# limit the range of characters the user can put into a textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have a textbox in a vb form and I want to limit the range of characters that the user can put into the textbox to:`" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890^-*()."`. The textbox is to insert SI Units into a database so i need consistent syntax. If the user types an invalid character into the textbox I would like the textbox to refuse to insert it, or remove it straight away, leaving the cursor in the same position within the textbox. I would also like the textbox to replace `"/"` with `"^(-"` and place the cursor before this.

I have found some code elsewhere which I have edited to do this but the code is bad, it activates on text changed within the textbox. This causes the code to fail, when the user inputs a disallowed value the code it activates itself when it tries to changes the text within the textbox.

Here is my code, the textbox starts with the contents `"enter SI Units"` from the form designer.

```
Private Sub TxtQuantityTextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSIUnit.TextChanged

If txtSIUnit.Text = "Enter SI Units" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim charactersAllowed As String = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890^-*()."
    Dim Text As String = txtSIUnit.Text
    Dim Letter As String
    Dim SelectionIndex As Integer = txtSIUnit.SelectionStart
    Dim Change As Integer




    Letter = txtSIUnit.Text.Substring(SelectionIndex - 1, 1)
    If Letter = "/" Then
        Text = Text.Replace(Letter, "^(-")
        SelectionIndex = SelectionIndex - 1
    End If



    Letter = txtSIUnit.Text.Substring(SelectionIndex - 1, 1)
    If charactersAllowed.Contains(Letter) = False Then
        Text = Text.Replace(Letter, String.Empty)
        Change = 1
    End If


    txtSIUnit.Text = Text
    txtSIUnit.Select(SelectionIndex - Change, 0)

    If txtQuantity.Text <> "Enter Quantity" Then
        If cmbStateRateSumRatio.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            bttAddQUAtoDatabase.Enabled = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub`
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the KeyPress event.  Set e.Handled to true if you don't like the character.  It's a one-liner:

```
Private Const AllowedChars = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890^-*()."

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar >= " "c AndAlso Not AllowedChars.Contains(e.KeyChar) Then e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In the textbox's `KeyDown` event, check `e.KeyCode`. This lets you prevent certain characters from being handled. There's an example on the [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx#Y342) documentation.